# Program does not prompt input after the first time [c++]

Tags: c++, function, pointers, input

Here is my program, it is using c++ and I done it on MacOS VSCode.

Library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
```

Function:

```
float* read_data(int& size){
    int a_size = 0;
    static float a[10];
    float* temp = a;

    cout << "Please enter values, and press 'Q' when finished: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
        if (cin.fail()){
            break;
        }else{
            a_size++;
        }
    }
    cin.clear();

    size = a_size;

    return temp;
    
}
```

Main function:

```
int main(){
    int size1 = 10;
    int size2 = 10;
    int size3 = 0;
    float array[10];
    float addarray[10];
    float longarray[20];
    float* ptr = array;
    float* addptr = addarray;
    float* longptr = longarray;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    ptr = read_data(size1);
    
    cout << setw(15) << "Original array" << setw(5) << "=" << setw(5) << "{ " << *ptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++){
        cout << ", " << *(ptr + i);
    }
    cout << " }" << endl;


    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++){
        *(longptr + size3) = *(ptr + i);
        size3++;
    }

    addptr = read_data(size2);

    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++){
        *(longptr + size3) = *(addptr + i);
        size3++;
    }

    cout << setw(15) << "New array" << setw(5) << "=" << setw(5) << "{ " << *longptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < size3; i++){
        cout << ", " << *(longptr + i);
    }
    cout << " }" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The main objective of the program was to prompt the user for an array, maximum of 10 elements. Prompting the user was done using the float* read_data(int& size) function.

The program would echo or print out the inputted array.

After that, the user was prompt for a second time using the same function to get another array of elements, in this case is a list of float values.

Then, the program would use a dynamic data allocation (DMA) technique to combine the two array into one long array. The new array will be printed out and the program is terminated.

**Problem**
As I said before, the program are supposed to prompt the user for inputs every time the `read_data()` were called.

I called the function twice. It did run twice, but failed to prompt the user for input the second time around.

I thought the problem was due to the cin.fail() arguments. That is why I tried to mess with the cin.ignore() and cin.clear() either by removing them or only using one of them.

I am honestly at lost on what is the root of the problem.

Comment: And what's the actual goal of the assignment? There's is a lot to critique here, on top of the problem at hand.

Comment: So many questions here... Strange `static` array. No two instances of accessing an array using the same syntax. Not even sure where to begin...

Comment: I am a beginner in c++ and had been having a hard time with this code. I used `static` array since the array values changed from the inputted value without `static.` I saw the suggestion on a website, and thought it would help maintaining the array value after returning.

Answer (score 1):

The heart of the issue is that you want users to enter `'Q'`, a `char`, into your `float` variable.

Here's a small example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int a;
  std::cin >> a;

  if (std::cin.fail()) {
    std::cout << "Fail.\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "All clear.\n";
  }

  std::cin >> a;
  std::cout << (2 * a) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
Q
Fail.
0

~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
3
All clear.
3
6
```

So, you can see that you were on the right track. The issue is that if `std::cin` did fail, you are now responsible to clean up your mess.

`std::cin.clear()` is a good start. It resets the fail flag bits. *But* the stream is still in a bad state. What you haven't done is clean it up **completely**.

You're calling `std::cin.ignore()`, but leaving the parameter list empty.

Something like this is best practice:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  int a;
  std::cin >> a;

  if (std::cin.fail()) {
    std::cout << "Fail.\n";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cin.clear();
  } else {
    std::cout << "All clear.\n";
  }

  std::cin >> a;
  std::cout << (2 * a) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
Q
Fail.
3
6
```

While that should fix address the question, your code is still fundamentally broken.

---

**EDIT**

Here's a mini-code review:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>  // These includes
#include <cmath>      // are
#include <cstdlib>    // not
#include <string>     // used
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;  // Bad practice

// You should not attempt to return a C-style array
float* read_data(int& size){  // Why is the size being passed by reference?
    int a_size = 0;
    static float a[10];  // Not doing what you think
    float* temp = a;

    cout << "Please enter values, and press 'Q' when finished: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){  // Formatting; should be ") {"
        cin >> a[i];
        if (cin.fail()){  // Addressed above; root cause of your question
            break;
        }else{
            a_size++;
        }
    }
    cin.clear();

    size = a_size;

    return temp;
}

// While I assume the goal of the assignment is to get familiar with pointers,
// This assignment is trivial with vectors.
int main(){
    int size1 = 10;  // If declared const/constexpr, you'd only need one **
    int size2 = 10;  // These are bad names
    int size3 = 0;   // Front loading declarations is bad practice.
    float array[10];  // ** And could use that variable here to avoid the magic number
    float addarray[10];
    float longarray[20];  // Not dynamic per your requirements.
    float* ptr = array;   // Still not dynamic, also unnecessary given the prior declarations
    float* addptr = addarray;
    float* longptr = longarray;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    ptr = read_data(size1);

    // The first cout is not good, what do you think *ptr will print?
    cout << setw(15) << "Original array" << setw(5) << "=" << setw(5) << "{ " << *ptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++){
        cout << ", " << *(ptr + i);  // The pointers can still use array syntax
    }
    cout << " }" << endl;


    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++){
        *(longptr + size3) = *(ptr + i);
        size3++;
    }

    addptr = read_data(size2);

    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++){
        *(longptr + size3) = *(addptr + i);
        size3++;
    }

    // As soon as you start repeating yourself, consider writing a function.
    // The logic will only live in one place, and only need to be changed in
    // one place.
    cout << setw(15) << "New array" << setw(5) << "=" << setw(5) << "{ " << *longptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < size3; i++){
        cout << ", " << *(longptr + i);
    }
    cout << " }" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

A lot going on that is less than great. The biggest flub appears to be the `static` array. `static` in this scenario extends the lifetime of the variable until the end of the program. So, when you call this function the second time, you overwrite the first array with the second because there's only ever one array for every call of that function. In the future, I would refrain from grabbing random code online and just dumping it in your program unless you know what it does.

Now, let's move on to a working solution.

The first thing I'm going to do is state the requirements as I understood them.

1. Have the user enter data to fill two arrays of floats.
2. Each array should hold a **maximum** of ten elements.
3. The user enters `"Q"` to indicate that they are finished entering data.
4. Print the first array.
5. Tack the second array on to the end of the first, in a dynamic fashion.
6. Print the combined array.

Anytime you get an assignment, your first task should be to restate the problem in your own words. This will clarify requirements and you will demonstrate to yourself that you understand the problem to be solved.

What makes this interesting is the `"Q"` to quit. Note that I'm using double quotes. We will read *all* of our data as strings, and we have to convert to `float` as needed.

[`std::stof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) exists, but it's not as simple as just calling it. That function can throw exceptions, and we want to ensure that only actual float values get converted.

So we'll wrap that call in a function of our own. Here's an example:

```cpp
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class bad_user_input : public std::exception {
    const char* what() const noexcept override {
        return "User input was not valid.";
    }
};

float convert_string_to_float(const std::string& val) {
    std::size_t marker = 0;
    float f = 0.0f;
    try {
        f = std::stof(val, &marker);
    } catch(...) {
        throw bad_user_input();
    }

    // Was the entire value entered a float?
    if (marker != val.length()) {
        throw bad_user_input();
    }

    // Getting here means a valid float was entered.
    return f;
}

int main() {
    float f = 0.0f;
    // Test the function
    try {
        f = convert_string_to_float("5.6");
    } catch(...) {
        std::cerr << "Issue.\n";
    }
    std::cout << f << "\n\n";

    f = 0.0f;
    try {
        f = convert_string_to_float("5.6cat");
    } catch(...) {
        std::cerr << "Issue.\n";
    }
    std::cout << f << "\n\n";

    f = 0.0f;
    try {
        f = convert_string_to_float("Q");
    } catch(...) {
        std::cerr << "Issue.\n";
    }
    std::cout << f << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
❯ ./a.out
5.6

Issue.
0

In convert_string_to_float
stof: no conversion
Issue.
0
```

Now that we can convert strings to floats, with guarantees, we are ready to read values. To test that we're reading correctly, we also want to be able to print our arrays:

```cpp
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class bad_user_input : public std::exception {
    const char* what() const noexcept override {
        return "User input was not valid.";
    }
};

float convert_string_to_float(const std::string& val) {
    std::size_t marker = 0;
    float f = 0.0f;
    try {
        f = std::stof(val, &marker);
    } catch(...) {
        throw bad_user_input();
    }

    // Was the entire value entered a float?
    if (marker != val.length()) {
        throw bad_user_input();
    }

    // Getting here means a valid float was entered.
    return f;
}

void read_array_from_user(float* arr, int& size, const int maxCapacity, std::istream& sin = std::cin) {
    size = 0;
    std::string input;
    while (size < maxCapacity && std::getline(sin, input)) {
        if (input == "Q" || input == "q" || input.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            arr[size] = convert_string_to_float(input);
        } catch(const std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << "Bad input. Reason: " << e.what() << "\nTry again.\n";
            continue;
        }
        ++size;
    }
}

void print_array(float* arr, int size, std::ostream& sout = std::cout) {
    sout << "{ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        sout << arr[i] << (i == size - 1 ? " " : ", ");
    }
    sout << "}\n";
}

int main() {
    constexpr int maxArrayCapacity = 10;
    float arrayOne[maxArrayCapacity];
    int arrayOneSize = 0;
    read_array_from_user(arrayOne, arrayOneSize, maxArrayCapacity);
    print_array(arrayOne, arrayOneSize);
}
```

Output:

```
~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out
1
2
3
4
q
{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }

~/tmp took 3s 
❯ ./a.out
1
2
Q
{ 1, 2 }

~/tmp took 2s 
❯ ./a.out
1
2
3
4
5
6

{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }

~/tmp took 4s 
❯ ./a.out
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0

{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 }

~/tmp took 5s 
❯ compilecpp tmp_repair.cpp

~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 }

~/tmp took 4s 
❯ ./a.out
1
2
3
q
{ 1, 2, 3 }

~/tmp took 2s 
❯ ./a.out
1
2b
Bad input. Reason: User input was not valid.
Try again.
2
3
Q
{ 1, 2, 3 }

~/tmp took 3s 
❯ ./a.out
1
2
3
Q
{ 1, 2, 3 }

~/tmp took 2s 
❯ ./a.out
1
2
3

{ 1, 2, 3 }
```

So, we can read an array with a *maximum* of 10 values. The reading is robust enough to handle typos or obviously bad input. But we don't have to read 10 values, it's the maximum. We keep track of the actual size ourselves.

Take note on how simple the `main()` function is because we put our sub-tasks into their own functions.

Reading the second array only requires a few lines in our `main()` now.

```cpp
int main() {
    constexpr int maxArrayCapacity = 10;
    float arrayOne[maxArrayCapacity];
    int arrayOneSize = 0;
    read_array_from_user(arrayOne, arrayOneSize, maxArrayCapacity);
    print_array(arrayOne, arrayOneSize);

    float arrayTwo[maxArrayCapacity];
    int arrayTwoSize = 0;
    read_array_from_user(arrayTwo, arrayTwoSize, maxArrayCapacity);
    print_array(arrayTwo, arrayOneSize);
}
```

Easy-peasy there. Now we need to combine the arrays "dynamically."

We know the sizes of our two arrays, so we know the size of the final array. Now we just need to allocate the memory on the heap. I'm not going to use `new`, which is what I assume you're supposed to do. My reasoning is that C++ has had better methods for managing dynamic allocations since 2011.

```cpp
#include <memory>

// ...

int main() {
    constexpr int maxArrayCapacity = 10;
    float arrayOne[maxArrayCapacity];
    int arrayOneSize = 0;
    read_array_from_user(arrayOne, arrayOneSize, maxArrayCapacity);
    print_array(arrayOne, arrayOneSize);

    float arrayTwo[maxArrayCapacity];
    int arrayTwoSize = 0;
    read_array_from_user(arrayTwo, arrayTwoSize, maxArrayCapacity);
    print_array(arrayTwo, arrayTwoSize);

    int combinedArraySize = arrayOneSize + arrayTwoSize;
    // This is considered dynamic; it's allocated on the heap
    auto combinedArray = std::make_unique<float[]>(combinedArraySize);
    int idx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOneSize; ++i) {
        combinedArray[idx] = arrayOne[i];
        ++idx;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayTwoSize; ++i) {
        combinedArray[idx] = arrayTwo[i];
        ++idx;
    }
    print_array(combinedArray.get(), combinedArraySize);
}
```

Output:

```
~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out
1
2
q
{ 1, 2 }
3
4
5
q
{ 3, 4, 5 }
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
```

Hopefully, the most gnarly stuff is over where you get the user input, mostly due to the requirement that users can enter a letter to signal they're done. And that makes sense since now you have to do type conversions. Other languages like python make it possible with a lot less LOC (Lines Of Code) on your part. The task itself is not difficult, but ensuring users behave is a whole other beast. If you're allowed to assume well-behaved input will always be provided, you can simplify the code quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! And you're right, it's still broken T-T

Comment: @IvonneHartono Please see my edit, where I break down your code and present a working solution. While I doubt you could away with submitting the code in this answer (and that's by design), it will hopefully work as a sort of guide for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It's way more complicated than I thought.

Comment: It doesn't have to be is the thing. If I'd just written code using `std::vector`, a lot of the array nonsense would be much simpler. Verifying input is always non-trivial, though. Again, if you are allowed to assume good input, it also simplifies things greatly. But the mixing of input types (float or "Q") is what's requiring a lot of extra work.

Comment: The professor insisted the use of array to complete all his assignments. I tried asking him to help with my problem, and he ended up just revising the whole instructions. We no longer are required to make the read_data() function.